# Regex string to capture a track's Spotify URI or web link

Tags: python, regex, spotify

I'm trying to integrate Spotify features on my Twitch chat-bot.
All features of the bot is written in Python, using Spotipy.

One of them is, adding a song to my playing Spotify queue.
Following code would work for that purpose.

```
if re.match(r"spotify[\/:]track[\/:].+[\s?]", songreq_params[1]):
   spotify.add_to_queue(songreq_params[1], sp_device_id)
```

But it seems to me that **r"spotify[/:]track[/:].+[\s?]"** regular expression doesn't work to catch Spotify track URIs and URLs such as:

- https://open.spotify.com/track/3Mh4EaJcfM4v2hpY49rjg6?si=nFRVStM1TpCWWtaJGWNLsg
- spotify:track:3Mh4EaJcfM4v2hpY49rjg6

I'm curious if the problem is about the snippet's syntax or the regex.

Comment: You probably don't even need a regex, you could just split the url based on '?' and '/'.

Comment: `url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]`

Comment: I'll try splitting the search for URLs and URIs if I can't find the regex solution for both at the same time. Because, I'll use the regex in more occasions such as bulk search and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly modify the regex like this:

```
import re
a="spotify:track:3Mh4EaJcfM4v2hpY49rjg6"
re.findall(r"spotify[/:]*track[/:]*[A-Za-z0-9]+",a)
```

Do you also want to capture this link (https://open.spotify.com/track/3Mh4EaJcfM4v2hpY49rjg6?si=nFRVStM1TpCWWtaJGWNLsg)as well?

Check out this regex this will probably help better. Let me know if this works. it covers both

```
import re
a="spotify:track:3Mh4EaJcfM4v2hpY49rjg6"
b="https://open.spotify.com/track/3Mh4EaJcfM4v2hpY49rjg6?si=nFRVStM1TpCWWtaJGWNLsg"
re.findall(r"[\bhttps://open.\b]*spotify[\b.com\b]*[/:]*track[/:]*[A-Za-z0-9?=]+",b)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to capture both the URL and URI at the same time, only for tracks.

Comment: Updated version works perfectly for both now. Thanks!